# SOLVED: GCC Compare String IF else ( A way to verify that you have written a certain word )

Tags: gcc

I'm learning at GCC and while I was trying various solutions to verify the entry of a certain word, `IF Word = Word {do something;}`
It seems that in C it cannot be done directly and so I tried this solution that seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int CClose = 0;
    int VerifyS = 0;
    char PWord[30] ={'\0'};

    do {

        printf("\n Type a word: ");
        scanf(" %s", &PWord);

        VerifyS = strncmp(PWord, "exit", 4);

        if (!VerifyS){ CClose = 1;}else{ printf("\n The Word is:%s", PWord);}



    }while (CClose != 1);

    return 0;   
    }
```

I wanted to know if there is another way to do the same thing.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written is essentially the most common way to do this.  There is indeed no way in C to compare two strings in a single expression without calling a function.

You can cut out the temporary variable `VerifyS` if you like, by writing

```
if (!strncmp(pWord, "exit", 4)) { /...
```

or, perhaps slightly clearer

```
if (strncmp(pWord, "exit", 4) == 0) { /...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I split it in two lines to be more understandable.